# Tool for identifying PowerBuilder memory leaks issues

Tags: testing, memory, memory-leaks, powerbuilder

Our application is developed in PowerBuilder. We are facing memory leaks issues in that application. Is there any tool or technique to find memory leaks?

Comment: Hi, what do you experience?

Comment: Application slows down with time. Some time the application also crashes. Response time of the apllication gradually decreases

Comment: I assume that there is some kind of database also. Is the database also slowing down in these cases? Could it be a db issue (locking tables etc?). Is this issue in connection with working hours when many users log in?

Comment: Does the "leak" occur while the app is in a constant loop? (Garbage collection kicks in when the call stack is empty, so unless something is blocking the garbage collection, like a valid reference...) Are there external DLLs or controls that could be leaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There used to be a utility (CDMatch by Brian Dick) that would open a PowerBuilder profiling file (using PowerScript functions), identify objects that had been garbage collected, get their unique object ids and find each object's instantiation in the trace. Finding objects created and not explicitly destroyed are the type of memory leak that you can control in PowerScript. The web site this tool was on went dark a few years ago.

I've typically found lazy programming that just assumed garbage collection would deal with clean up in a timely fashion, but then the function or event got used in a big loop that didn't allow clean up before all the garbage build up caused a problem.

So, you can:

- Try to roll your own analysis tool as described above
- Toss in explicit GarbageCollect()s in strategic places to see if that "resolves" your problem

  - if it does, use that as a starting point to track down your problem and either explicitly DESTROY instances or re-use existing instances; it will always perform better)

Good luck,

Terry.

Answer (score -1):

There are **several tools** that may help to pinpoint memory leaks, but **none are dedicated to PB**:

- [DPus Light](http://ltearno.free.fr/dpus/) (promising tool, but unfortunately not evolving since 2011) focuses to GDI and memory leaks
- [Visual Leak Detector](http://vld.codeplex.com/) targets VC++ so can help with PBNI extensions (and could for PB itself as it is compiled with VC++, but...)
- tools like [Sys Internals Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) can help too by listing the handles (files, GDI resources, ...) owned by the application

**On the PB side**, one solution could be to run the application in debug mode with Just-in-time debugging enabled and add a way (temporary button on a window) to invoke `DebugBreak()` : while in the debugger view, you can take a look in the `Objects in memory` view that could show if there are suspicious number of objects alive, but it can only give clues and cannot tell where ther were created or why they are there.